# Reading a Multiline String into a Table as Opposed to a Text File

Tags: r, string

I have `/path/to/my/file.tstv`:

```
Date         Pr   Data
2016-07-27  0.45  "Prior 1."
2016-07-28  0.55  "Prior 2."
2016-07-29  0.65  "Prior 3."
```

And, with my R code:

```
table_variable <- read.table("/path/to/my/file.tsv", header=TRUE)
```

**Question:** How do I instead read this data directly into `table_variable` as an inline multiline string?

Something like:

```
table_variable <- read.table("
Date         Pr   Data
2016-07-27  0.45  "Prior 1."
2016-07-28  0.55  "Prior 2."
2016-07-29  0.65  "Prior 3."
", header=TRUE)
```

Comment: if you know the separator (looks like "\t" to me), you can use the `sep=` argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This does what you want.  The main point is the `text=`. Notice that I changed your surrounding double quotes to single quotes.

```
table_variable <- read.table(text=
'Date         Pr   Data
2016-07-27  0.45  "Prior 1."
2016-07-28  0.55  "Prior 2."
2016-07-29  0.65  "Prior 3."
', header=TRUE)
```